# How to use XmlSerializer from inside ReadXml()

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to understand how to use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize `<n>` instances of a nested class from within the `ReadXml()` method of the outer class. What I'm running into is that the nested call to `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` causes nodes to be skipped.

The XML document looks something like this:

```
<outerType>
    <innerType id="1">structure</innerType>
    <innerType id="2">structure</innerType>
    <otherElement />
</outerType>
```

The rules for deserializing `outerType` require implementing `IXmlSerializable`.  But `innerType` can be deserialized by just using XmlSerializer.Deserialize().  The `ReadXml()` method for OuterType ends up looking something like this:

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Name == "innerType")
        {
            XmlSerializer innerSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InnerType));
            InnerType obj = (InnerType)innerSer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        else
            // Do some other logic
    }
}
```

On the first time through the loop, the type variable receives the structure contained in the `<innerType id="1"/>` element.  But the loop never encounters the `<innerType id="2"/>` element.

After playing with this in the debugger, I believe what's happening is that before the call to `innerSer.Deserialize()`, reader is pointing to the opening tag for `<innerType id="1"/>`, and immediately afterward, it's pointing to the opening tag for `<innerType id="2"/>`.  At the top of the loop, the call to `XmlReader.Read()` advances `reader` to the next element, and `<innerType id="2"/>` is never read.

Some solutions I've seen for deserializing a collection of objects suggest something along the lines of:

```
            XmlSerializer innerSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InnerType));
            InnerType obj1 = (InnerType)innerSer.Deserialize(reader);
            InnerType obj2 = (InnerType)innerSer.Deserialize(reader);
```

but in my particular case, I need to work with `<n>` instances of `InnerType`.

What I've found to work is to create a second XmlReader, containing a copy of the `InnerType` sub-tree, as in:

```
            XmlSerializer innerSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InnerType));
            XmlReader subTree = reader.ReadSubtree();
            InnerType obj = (InnerType)innerSer.Deserialize(subTree);
```

Is this the intended way to do this? Is there a better way to do this without creating an additional reader?